# How to parse an object sent from react frontend in express.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

So in my react front-end, I am using the 'react-drop-to-upload' module to allow the user to drag a file and upload. I followed the example on the npm module page and created a handler called handleDrop. The code looks like:

```
    handleDrop(files) {
      var data = new FormData();

      alert((files[0]) instanceof File);
      files.forEach((file, index) => {
        data.append('file' + index, file);
      });

      fetch('/file_upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
      });
    }
```

At my express backend, I have the following code:

```
app.post('/file_upload', function(req , res){
  var body = '';
  req.on('data', function (data) {
      body += data;
        });
  var post = "";
  req.on('end', function () {
      //post = qs.parse(body);
      console.log(body);
      // this won't create a buffer for me
      //var fileBuffer = new Buffer(body);
      //console.log(fileBuffer.toString('ascii'));
      //pdfText(body,  function(err, chunks) {
          //console.log(chunks);
      //});
  });

  //console.log(typeof post);
});
```

If I drop a txt file and do a console log on the body, it would give me:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryqlp9eomS0BxhFJkQ

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file0"; filename="lec16.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

The content of my data!
------WebKitFormBoundaryqlp9eomS0BxhFJkQ--
```

I am trying to use the pdfText module which takes in a buffer or a pathname to the pdf file, extract text from it into an array of text 'chunks' . I want to convert the body object into a buffer using var fileBuffer = new Buffer(body); but that won't work. Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a parser for multi-part data. You can look into `multer` regarding that.

Example code for you,

```
app.post('/file_upload', function(req , res){
  var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: tmpUploadsPath
    });
    var upload = multer({
        storage: storage
    }).any();

    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.end('Error');
        } else {
            console.log(req.body);
            req.files.forEach(function(item) {
                // console.log(item);
                // do something with the item,
                const data = fs.readFileSync(item.path);
                console.log(data);
            });
            res.end('File uploaded');
        }
    });
});
```

To understand the example code in depth, head [here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). Remember, you will get the file data as a buffer and not as actual data.

Comment: Thank you so much. The example code works like a charm. I'd definitely go through the documentation in detail. Thanks again for your help!